# Update operation violates unique constraint

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to implement a "**shift** by year" operation in my **Entity Framework** application.

To simplify things, let's suppose I have an entity / table that has a foreign key **FK** to some other table and a **YEAR** (int, int). Users may shift the entity years to the future, so I need to copy data from 2017 to 2018 and so forth.

There's a restriction in the database that says that the pair (FK, YEAR) must be **unique**.

When I perform the "shift" in memory and send the changes to the database with **SaveChanges** I receive an error from the database that I'm violating the unique constraint. I suppose that it is trying to perform the update row by row, therefore the violation.

If I sort the collection by year descending (so no duplicates happen if the rows are sent one by one) the same error happens.

My workaround is to **delete** the old data and **insert** new data with the new years, but I think there might be a cleaner solution...

Comment: have you tried disabling that constraint first, doing the update, and then reenabling it?

Comment: You'd have to set `identity insert` to on, do the operation and turn it off again

Comment: You don't want to have multiple rows with the same `ID` value, assuming that it is also your Primary Key. If you're trying to add a new record instead of updating the existing record, you should never have the same `ID`, therefore your Unique Constraint is most likely pointless since the one value will always be changing. If instead, you're updating that record, you have something else going on. We'll need to see how the database table is defined, and what code you're using to perform your **shift** and save.

Comment: If you want to shift the year up with that constraint, you have to do it in order  from the highest year to the lowest, saving the changes after updating each row, for ex if you have the years 2015, 2016, 2017 start by updating 2017 to 2018, save, update 2016 to 2017, save, update 2015 to 2016, save. this way you'll never have duplicates. obviously enclose all the saves in an transaction

Comment: AgapwIesu I'd prefer not switching off constraints to avoid bugs in the code... it may happen that there's a bug in the code that is actually duplicating rows.
DiskJunky, krillgar: I made the case too much simple: the real case is a unique constraint with a (SOME_FK, YEAR, SOME_BIT). So, the PK unique that you mention does not protect this case. I'll edit the question to avoid misunderstanding.
JoaoFSA: I tried that and it didn't work, as I stated in the question. Thank you guys for your feedback.

Comment: Could you post the code that performs the shift?

Comment: @Luis are you saving after changing each row? or calling SaveChanges only once in the end?

Comment: Seems like it would be a good idea to post the code for the unique constraint and some C# code that we can execute to see the error happen.

Comment: @JoaoFSA You gave me an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by inverting the order and saving item by item after modifying. It's not very clean to run so many SaveChanges but the overall process is rather complex and it's using transactions, so it's not a big deal.

I had to make some more changes because users can shift years to the past or to the future, in which case I must / mustn't reverse the order, but to simplify this very issue let's say that it's solved if I **reverse** the order **and save item by item**.